'Cinema4D-exported' OBJ issues - Weird normals recalc result
I'm fairly new to Blender - only started learning this year. So this could be something painfully obvious to a lot of you.
I'm trying to import a drawing I did a while back when I used Cinema4D for most things.
I exported an OBJ, after reading that it was probably the best format for going between the two.
First of all, the model came in gigantic (so I resized it and applied scale), and secondly on 'recalculating normals' after seeing the normals 'in red', I got a funny result, in that the shading looked a bit like it had been rotated slightly or something - maybe a UV thing?
Not sure exactly what it might be and was hoping someone might recognise the problem.
Thanks in advance.

Please add an image of the problem you're seeing and if it's not too large share your Blend file. You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the full link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it.

Normals could be done by faces you don't have to recalculate all at once. Cinema 4D uses a phong tag to calculate the angles between normals and it's probably not 100% compatible with blender.

Thanks guys. I'll follow up on these suggestions when I'm up and about again, tomorrow. Much appreciated
